# How to keep select selected with the old() function - laravel blade

Tags: laravel-blade

i have a search that is driven by a select and i need the option i chose to remain checked when i submit the search, so i used laravel's old() function inside an @if.

```
<select class="contas_select form-control" name="conta_id" tabindex="1">           
            <option value=" ">&nbsp;</option>
            @foreach($contas as $conta)
                    <option value="{{ old('conta_id') }}" @if( old('conta_id') == request()->conta_id) selected="selected" @endif>
                    {{ $conta->nome }}
                    </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

but it doesn't work, I don't know why, but it replaces what I selected with the last element inside the option. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There is no need to add SOLVED to your question's title. When you mark an answer with the green checkmark, that accomplishes the same thing, and the question is highlighted differently to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using old('conta_id') as the value for each option in the select element. This is causing the issue because old('conta_id') will always return the same value for each option within the loop.

To fix this, you should set the option value to the ID of each $conta, and then check if that ID matches the value of old('conta_id'). Here's how you can adjust your code:

```
<select class="contas_select form-control" name="conta_id" tabindex="1">           
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    @foreach($contas as $conta)
        <option value="{{ $conta->id }}" @if(old('conta_id') == $conta->id) selected="selected" @endif>
            {{ $conta->nome }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: didn't work :( 
it didn't take the last element of the option, but it didn't keep the element selected before submitting the search

Comment: Sorry about that. Will test the scenario a bit more.

Comment: No need to apologize, thanks for your help! 

I did something that apparently worked, but I confess I found it a bit strange:

`@if(old('conta_id') == '')
          <option value="{{ $conta->id }}" 
          {{ ( $conta->id == request()->conta_id ) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
           {{ $conta->nome }}
         </option>
  @else
       <option value="{{ $conta->id }}"> {{ $conta->nome }}</option>
  @endif`

Comment: I am glad you came right. You can add an update to your question and mark it as solved in case someone encounters a similar issue.